# insert a function call of char * parameter in llvm

Tags: llvm

In a llvm pass, how can I create a function of a char* parameter and insert a function call to it before the terminator instruction of a basic block? Please be specific.

Thanks,
Bo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LLVM online demo should be able to help you: http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi
With it, you can not only see the LLVM IR generated for a program you type in, but you can also have it show the LLVM C++ code needed to generate the IR. For example, I tried:

```
void f(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *p;
  int i = 1;
  if (i)
      f(p);
  return i;
}
```

The results are fairly easy to decipher.

Comment: That is a smart way. But it seems the automatically generated code is kid of redundant. Is there a simple way to do this? For example, I'd like to insert a function call, the parameter of which is the name of the function being passed.

Comment: wow, didn't know they had setup that cgi script, very nice, thank you!!